# 'NoneType' object is not iterable error on menu python

Tags: python

1.so i wrote a code for a menu python whereby i can edit add etc. the error pops up when first i added a car to the list and when i want to display the full carlist(option 5) after adding a new car, it has an error. 'NoneType' object is not iterable error on menu python. it works fine if i do not add a car to the carlist. anyone know where i went wrong? could not figure it out

this is the full error traceback

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f7190cf7df27> in <module>
    144         Carlist()
    145 
--> 146 print(Carlist())

<ipython-input-3-f7190cf7df27> in Carlist()
    133         print("-"*100+'\n'+ ' '*40 +"Add Product"+'\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
    134         Carlist_2.append(carlist_add())
--> 135         Carlist()
    136 
    137     elif choice ==3:

<ipython-input-3-f7190cf7df27> in Carlist()
    114                 print (Carlist_title[count_title]+": "+ Carlist_2[int(choice)-1][count_title])
    115                 count_title += 1
--> 116         Carlist()
    117 
    118 

<ipython-input-3-f7190cf7df27> in Carlist()
    114                 print (Carlist_title[count_title]+": "+ Carlist_2[int(choice)-1][count_title])
    115                 count_title += 1
--> 116         Carlist()
    117 
    118 

<ipython-input-3-f7190cf7df27> in Carlist()
    124         print("-"*100+'\n'+ ' '*40 +"Display Full Car List"+'\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
    125         for row in Carlist_2:
--> 126             for column in row:
    127                 print(column,end=" ")
    128             print()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

```
Carlist_1 = []
Carlist_1.append("Toyota Prius")
Carlist_1.append("Honda City")
Carlist_1.append("Subaru Forester")
Carlist_1.append("Honda Jazz")
Carlist_1.append("Tesla Model 3")
Carlist_1.append("Mercedes-Benz")
    
Carlist_2=[]
Carlist_2.append(['Toyota Prius','MPV','Hybrid','140000'])
Carlist_2.append(['Honda City','Saloon','Economical','75000'])
Carlist_2.append(['Subaru Forester','SUV','Adventure','140000'])
Carlist_2.append(['Honda Jazz','Hatchback','Compact','70000'])
Carlist_2.append(['Tesla Model 3','Coupe','Electric Vehicle ','120000'])
Carlist_2.append(['Mercedes-Benz','Cabriolet','Turbo-charged ','250000'])

Carlist_title = ["Model","Type ","Specs","Price"]

 

def carlist_add():
    model=input("What is the model?")
    types=input("What is the type?")
    spec=input("What is the specs?")
    price=input("(input NUMBERS only) What is the price? $")
    carlist_add2=[model,types,spec,price]
    Carlist_1.append(model)
    Carlist_2.append(carlist_add2)

def edit():  
    print('-'*100+'\n'+' '*40+'Edit\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
    
    count = 0
    while count < len(Carlist_1):
        count += 1
        print (str(count)+". "+Carlist_1[count-1])
            
    product=int((input("Which car details do you want to edit?")))


    print("Current Product Model: ", Carlist_2[product-1][0])
    newmodel=input("Enter New Model: ")
    Carlist_2[product-1][0]=newmodel
    
    print("Current Product Type: ", Carlist_2[product-1][1])
    newtype=input("Enter New Type: ")
    Carlist_2[product-1][1]=newtype
    
    print("Current Product Spec: ", Carlist_2[product-1][2])
    newspec=input("Enter New Spec: ")
    Carlist_2[product-1][2]=newspec
    
    print("Current Product Price: ", Carlist_2[product-1][3])
    newprice=input("Enter New Price: ")
    Carlist_2[product-1][3]=newprice

    print ("\nThe new description is as follows: ")
    print(Carlist_2[product-1],"\n")
    Carlist_1[product-1]=newmodel


def Carlist_delete():
    print('-'*100+'\n'+
          ' '*40+'Delete Car\n'+
          '-'*100+'\n')
    count = 0
    while count < len(Carlist_1):
        count += 1
        print (str(count)+". "+Carlist_1[count-1])
        
    delete_input=input("Select an option:")
    print('-'*100+'\n'+
          ' '*40+'Car deleted\n'+
          '-'*100+'\n')
    Carlist_1.pop(int(delete_input)-1)
    Carlist_2.pop(int(delete_input)-1)
    for row in Carlist_2:
        for column in row:
            print(column,end=" ")
        print()


def Carlist():
    
    print('-'*100+'\n'+
          ' '*40+'Main Menu\n'+
          '-'*100+'\n')
    
    print ("1. Display Car list")
    print ("2. Add Product")
    print ("3. Edit product")
    print ("4. Delete product")
    print ("5. Display Full car list")
    print ("0. Leave")
   
   
    choice = int(input("Select an option:"))
    
    if choice == 1:
        print("-"*100+'\n'+ ' '*40 +"Display carlist"+'\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
        count = 0
        while count < len(Carlist_1):
            count += 1
            print (str(count)+". "+Carlist_1[count-1]) 
        
        choice = input("Select a Car:")
   
        print('-'*100+'\n'+
              ' '*40+'Display Car Details\n'+
              '-'*100+'\n')
    
        count_title = 0 
        while count_title < len(Carlist_2[int(choice)-1]): 
                print (Carlist_title[count_title]+": "+ Carlist_2[int(choice)-1][count_title])
                count_title += 1
        Carlist()
        
        
    elif choice==0:
        print("-"*100+'\n'+ ' '*40 +"Exited from Main Menu"+'\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
        
                       
    elif choice==5:
        print("-"*100+'\n'+ ' '*40 +"Display Full Car List"+'\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
        for row in Carlist_2:
            for column in row: 
                print(column,end=" ")
            print()
        Carlist()
    
    
    elif choice ==2:
        print("-"*100+'\n'+ ' '*40 +"Add Product"+'\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
        Carlist_2.append(carlist_add())
        Carlist()
    
    elif choice ==3:
        edit()
        Carlist()
      

    elif choice ==4:
        Carlist_delete()
        Carlist()
     
print(Carlist())
```

Comment: You are appending a 'None' object to the end of the list(Carlist_2) when adding a new product. Try to find where you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Carlist_2.append(carlist_add())` with `carlist_add()`  when choice is 2

```
    elif choice ==2:
        print("-"*100+'\n'+ ' '*40 +"Add Product"+'\n'+'-'*100+'\n')
        carlist_add()
        Carlist()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really interesting..
If we look at line 135 of your code,we can see you are calling carlist_add()

```
Carlist_2.append(carlist_add())
```

**What does Carlist_add() do?**

It appends a new element to carlist_2 and carlist_1.
But it does not return anything.

But in line 135 you are calling carlist_add() as an arguement of append(). So, after carlist_add() does it's job,it return a NoneType object to the append() function, and the append function does it's job and adds a NoneType at the end of your carlist_2.

TO solve it, simply..
Just call the carlist_add() without the append function.

```
carlist_add()
```